# Render isomorphic React component which requires window object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, graphql-js

I have an isomorphic React application, with components being rendered on the server-side. I wish to use a 3rd party React component: ([GraphiQL)](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql), and am rendering as such:

```
var GraphiQLComponent = React.createElement(GraphiQL, { fetcher: graphQLFetcher}, "");

router.get('/graphiql', function (req, res) {
  res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(GraphiQLComponent));
});
```

However, this component uses the window object: `window.localStorage` and `window.addEventListener`, and when I try to load the page in the browser, I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Can I render React components which use the window object, on the server? If so, what do I need to do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use libraries that depend on window in your components.
or
Only use these libraries in `componentDidMount` and exclude them for **prerendering** (make sure your component don't render different in prerendering or it doesn't work).

I figured I shouldn’t import the library outside the class definition, but instead require it in the `componentDidMount` method or a called method thereof.

So, instead of:

```
...
import MyWindowDependentLibrary from 'path/to/library';
...
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() { MyWindowDependentLibrary.doWork(); }
    ...
}
```

I did:

```
// removed import
...
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        const MyWindowDependentLibrary = require( 'path/to/library' );
        MyWindowDependentLibrary.doWork();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can!

Just do not run that piece of code until window is defined!
I also imagine you could use those functions in a componentDidMount() lifecycle function.

```
if (window !== 'undefined') {
    // do your window required stuff
}
```

I've used this multiple times in components being rendered server-side, and it works like a charm.